# Why do I get "Database already exists" when I'm using "AttachDbFileName" when I move the solution to another directory?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have an application JigSaw that uses a database `TopScores.mdf` which it is not included in the project. What I want to do is make the application find the database in application's folder. So for example if I move the `.exe` file and the database file from debug folder to desktop the application should use the database from desktop and not search for it in debug folder.

If I let them in debug folder there is no problem and the connection to database is established, but when I put them on desktop I get this :

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. Database 'D:\Programing\Projects Visual Studio 2010\JigSaw\JigSaw\bin\Debug\TopScores.mdf' already exists. Choose a different database name. Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\Addy\Desktop\Jigsaw\TopScores.mdf' as database TopScores.mdf

My connection string is :

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
string connString = @"server  =.\sqlexpress; Database=TopScores.mdf; trusted_connection=TRUE; AttachDbFileName= "+@appPath+@"\TopScores.mdf";
conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
```

Sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because you don't leverage the `User Instance=true;` when you connect to it. You literally told SQL Server to attach the database to the running SQL instance from the directory you first loaded it from.

Detach the database by hand from the running SQL instance, change your connection string to use `User Instance=true;`, run it from the `Debug` folder, and then run it from the `Desktop`, and you'll see success.

Comment: Thank you but I think I followed your steps and i still get the same error. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @adrian, did you connect to the server via Management Studio and detach the database by hand?

Comment: I get this : "Cannot detach a suspect or recovery pending database.It must be repaired or dropped." Should I check the Drop Connections box and then try to detach it ?

Comment: @AdrianTanase, no that's not going to fix it. You'll need to `Delete` the database instead. But that's okay, you have a copy of it on your `Desktop`, so after you delete it you can move that copy back into the `Debug` folder. **Don't forget to change your connection string before loading the application again after you get this done.**

Comment: After I deleted the database, it was still present in management studio so i tried to detach it but I got the same error. So I just changed the connstring and after that I put the database's copy in Debug, ran it from there and after that when I ran it from Desktop I got the error from above (same). Thank you for your time but I am a noob :(

Comment: The problem was this part in connString : "Database=TopScores.mdf;" After I deleted that it worked just fine:) Thank you!

Comment: @AdrianTanase, fantastic! I'm glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 3):

change setting in your connection string from "Database=TopScores.mdf" to something different, say: "Database=TopScores_brand_new_connection" do not create/delete/rename files in any file/database server. do it in the connection string only. Do not add dots, extensions etc.

Answer (score -1):

just rename ur .mdf file ... eg. from MNGMT.mdf to M_1(something you want). change your contact string...hope so it will help u.. in my case it is executing correctly on other pc as well as in my pc.. just copy your .mdf file into you project ..

```
string dbPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\M_1.mdf";
string myServer = Environment.MachineName;
DataTable servers = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
            for (int i = 0; i < servers.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (myServer == servers.Rows[i]["ServerName"].ToString()) ///// used to get the servers in the local machine////
                {
                    if ((servers.Rows[i]["InstanceName"] as string) != null)
                        servername = (servers.Rows[i]["ServerName"] + "\\" + servers.Rows[i]["InstanceName"]);
                    else
                        servername = ""+servers.Rows[i]["ServerName"];
                }
            }
connetionString = "Data Source=" + servername + ";AttachDbFilename=" + dbPath + ";Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;User Instance=True";
```