# GetDatabase from Curent directory

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-express

I try to open a connection with a database from curent directory, and I searched on google and I found that I need to use " System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() ". and I recive this error

> Database 'D:\Work\C#\DatabaseLoginPassProj\DatabaseLoginPassProj\Database1.mdf' already exists. Choose a different database name.
>   Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\Mihai\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\BazaDeDataIndependenta\bin\Debug\Database1.mdf' as database 'Database1.mdf'.

this is my code

```
 private void InregistrareBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connstring = @" server=.\sqlexpress;
                               Database = Database1.mdf;
                               trusted_connection = true;
                               AttachDBFileName = " + System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +
        @"\Database1.mdf;";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
        conn.Open();





    }
```

Thanks.

Ps: I don't want to specify the full path of the DB because I need to make the program working on every pc.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090625/why-do-i-get-database-already-exists-when-im-using-attachdbfilename-when-i

Comment: Thanks,  i added  "User Instance=true;" , and changed the name of the database to something else, and it works, strange thing tho that C# dosen't like " Database1.mdf "...

Comment: It has nothing to do with c#. You attached the database to your Express instance in a normal context. That means permanent. You can't attach a database twice. The user Instance livetime is connected to your apps livetime and attaching is only valid in that instance. So you can attach it later to a new different instance,